# Screen Scraping a Database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, screen-scraping

I've been searching for help with screen scraping for the windows phone 7 but cannot find any help relevant to what i want. The basis of my application is to take a phone number typed in an input box on the device -> pass it to a website's searchbox -> search the website's SQL database -> pass the raw results back to the phone and display them in a table.

I have permission from the website owner to use his online database for this purpose.

Is this possible and, if so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After some extra research I've found that with using the POST method I can send the data needed to the search box on the website and the results are successfully found but I am unsure on how to display the results onto the application itself? I know the data is successfully sent via packets viewed in WireShark. Thanks again.

Code for POST:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("search_name", "Google"); //Test Search
        parameters.Add("submit", "Search");
        PostClient proxy = new PostClient(parameters);
        proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                //Process the result...
                data = e.Result;
            }
        };
        proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.SITE.com/search.php", UriKind.Absolute));
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(, UriKind.Absolute));`
```

Comment: There are many questions on screen scraping with C#/.NET (see related sidebar at bottom right).  The answers to these questions should be mostly applicable to WP7 also.  If there is a specific problem you're having getting one of these solutions to work on WP7, then you need to provide more detail about the problem in your post.

Comment: You should probably post your edit as an answer and accept it versus putting the answer in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the website's UI and screen scraping the results, I would create an HTTP request similar to or the same as the request generated by the web page (this will probably be a POST request containing form data). I would then send this to the web server and use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the required data from the response.

Effectively, the website presents you with an HTTP API using HTML as the message format. Use this directly, rather than using a client side rendering of these messages, which ultimately is designed for user interaction rather than code interaction.

Comment: Thank you @Adam Ralph, I'll give that a go now, as you posted about it I had just found some information leading me down that path but the Htmlagilitypack seems like it will be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible/allowed to access other applications running on the Windows Phone.

So this is not possible unless the publishers of the other applications connect to your website/webservice.

NB: When Windows Phone 8 come out and it is the same as or similar to Windows 8 there might be contracts available that allow the wiring up of application like this. (This is just guessing)